# How to fix ValueError with Pandas iterrows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I'm trying to write a function that generates a barplot given a PD column, and a list of labels for the legend. I have categorical data that's been numerically encoded, so the default labels are just numbers that I want to change back to string values. Here's my code:

```
legend_labels = ["label 1", "label 2"]

def plot_percentages(col, legend_labels):

    plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))

    ax = sns.barplot(x="x", y="x", hue=col, data=df, 
                     estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(df) * 100)

    ax.set(ylabel="Percentage")

    plt.xticks([0, 1], ['A', "B"])

    L=plt.legend()

    for idx, val in pd.DataFrame(legend_labels).iterrows():
    L.get_texts()[idx].set_text(val)

ax
```

It returns the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you converting a list into a df just to iterate through it? Just grab the labels from the list directly.

Comment: Because then I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterrows.'" Remoing that attribute gives me the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)." I need to pull both the list item and its position in the list, but I'm not sure how to do that without converting it to a df first.

Comment: But why use iterrows() at all? ```for val in legend_labels:``` works just fine. Or if you need idx then ```for idx, val in enumerate(legend_labels):```

Comment: Yes, enumerate() was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I have added as an answer. Drop a comment if still having trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to not use `iterows()` here but rather just a simple for loop.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(legend_labels):
    L.get_texts()[idx].set_text(val)
```